# How to align the slash in the table?

Tags: tables

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{slashbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{} \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}{*}{\slashbox{}{}} & & &\\
        \cline{2-4} & & & \\
        \cline{2-4} & & & \\
        \cline{2-4} & & & \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} & \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]
this is how the table should turn out, but there are problems with the dash in column 1.
It seems to me something with the size, because when I increase this column, the line falls into place

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: @user202729 I have already corrected

Comment: [formatting - Slashbox with tables: Adjusting the diagonal separator for multiple rows - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114174/slashbox-with-tables-adjusting-the-diagonal-separator-for-multiple-rows) / [Complicated table with multirows and multicolumns slashbox - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566725/complicated-table-with-multirows-and-multicolumns-slashbox) has some alternative methods. No fix though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slashbox is rather old and undocumented. It's not in TeXLive.
I use diagbox which has good documentation instead and does the same thing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{}    \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{\diagbox[dir=SW,height=4\line]{}{}} &   &  & \\
    \cline{2-4}                                         &   &  & \\
    \cline{2-4}                                         &   &  & \\
    \cline{2-4}                                         &   &  & \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}                              &        \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: diagbox]

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way using `nicematrix`. Of course you can make any adjustments you need: column width, color, line thickness, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines]
\Block{1-4}{} \\
\Block{4-1}{} & & & \\
 & & & \\
 & & & \\
 & & & \\
\Block{1-3}{} & \\
\CodeAfter
    \tikz
    \draw (6-|1) -- (2-|2);
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I only need it through slashbox and tabular

Comment: @AndrijMatviiv: I'm not certain, but I believe `slashbox` was only designed to draw from top-left to bottom-right. You could try the package `diagbox`, which will draw either way, but I don't know that it's compatible with `multirow` in the way you need.

Comment: I just see that it works in all examples, but for some reason it conflicts with me